# YouTube Live Streaming and Timezone Information (GMT) in Creator Studio

Tags: youtube-livestreaming-api

We are making a live broadcasting software for YouTube.  Following LiveStream API guide, we could successfully broadcast our live event.

One issue we encountered, however, is that we never get the correct GMT information for the event.
For example, even though we are on live from from South Korea, which is GMT+9, but according to the creator studio's page, all live events were

broadcasted from GMT-7.

Currently we’re using the following API:  snippet.scheduledStartTime
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts

The usage is like snippet.scheduledStartTime(1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
As guided in http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Is there any issue with Google's API for Timezone setting?

Thanks.

Comment: did you find the answer? same problem here!